# How to set oracle v$session.program or v$session.process through jboss with XA connections

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jboss

I am trying to set the `v$session.program` or `v$session.process` connection property via `jboss` to a value so i can distinguish the different jboss instances. We are using xa connections.  [This](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToSpecifyOracleConnectionProgramProperty) site shows how to do it for local tx datasource but not XA. I read some places that said- with XA datasources you can not achieve this. Is that true? We really need to be able to see which session correlates to which process.

[This](https://community.jboss.org/thread/72628) person also has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know jboss, but perhaps DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO is helpful for you -- see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_appinf.htm#CHECEIEB

Especially have a look upon:

> DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO (
>     client_info IN VARCHAR2);
>
> Parameters
>   client_info
>
> Supplies any additional information about the client application.
>   This information is stored in the V$SESSION view. 
>   Information exceeding 64 bytes is truncated.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8256692/131929) the answer to which suggests setting this property:

```
<xa-datasource-property name="connectionProperties">v$session.program=YourUniqueName</xa-datasource-property>
```